# problems with the resolution of loaded images from url

Tags: android, android-layout, load, imageview

I am loading images in an ImageView from url. (from RSS feed)

The problem is that the resolution of the loaded image is lower than the original image !!

I searched Stackoverflow and found that the solution is to set the "inScaled" option to false to prevent image re-scaling.
but, this solution didn't work for me.

Here is the code:

```
    URL feedImage= new URL(img_link);
    HttpURLConnection conn= (HttpURLConnection)feedImage.openConnection();
    InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
    BitmapFactory.Options  BFoptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    BFoptions.inScaled = false;
    Bitmap img = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is,null, BFoptions);
    int density = img.getDensity(); Log.e("img", "Image density is " + density);
    int width =img.getWidth(); Log.e("img", "Image width is " + width);
    int height  = img.getHeight(); Log.e("img", "Image height is " + height);

    my_image.setImageBitmap(img);
```

The variables density, width and height are lower than the original image's values.

and here is a part of my layout:

```
<RelativeLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">


            <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/joke_image"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"         
                    android:contentDescription="temp description"/>


            <ScrollView
                    android:id="@+id/SV"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="30dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/background"
                    android:paddingTop="10dp"
                    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                    android:paddingRight="10dp"
                    android:paddingBottom="50dp">

                    <!-- bla 
                         bla 
                         bla  

                         -->


            </ScrollView>   
</RelativeLayout>
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally it was solved :)

It appeared to be not related to the code or the ImageViews, .....

All the images in the RSS feeds are thumbnails ... which is the reason that they appear small in the app but large in the website.

So the solution was to replace the "_s.jpg" at the end of each image's url with "_n.jpg" :)

I hope this answer will help someone else :)